# VSTS WIki Using HTML Img Tag

Tags: azure-devops, markdown

Because I wanted to be able to re-size images in markdown I've been using the HTML `img` and specifying the desired width/height.

I'm referencing the image using a relative path, so for example for markdown in the same directory as an images folder I'd write:

`<img src="./Images/MyImage.png" width="600">`

This has all worked fine using Visual Studio Code but when the markdown is pushed to the VSTS Wiki it isn't rendering the image.

Is this a bug or is the `img` tag not supported?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by below answer? any update?

Comment: I'm sure that will work but its a shame the Wiki doesn't support standard syntax.

Comment: Well, The Wiki of course support the standard HTML syntax, the problem in you scenario is that the image cannot be found as the path is incorrect when pushed the md file and images to VSTS. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following syntax to resize them (see **`=WIDTHxHEIGHT`** at the end):

**Notice though that the syntax to support image resizing is only supported in pull requests and the Wiki.**

```
![Image alt text]($/project/folder/_img/markdown-guidance/image.png =WIDTHxHEIGHT)
```

So for your use case I would use (in your markdown files):

```
![Image alt text](./Images/MyImage.png =600x)
```

---

Please refer to the following documentation for images in markdown.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=vsts#images

Comment: The format should be `![Image alt text](./Images/MyImage.png =600x800)` or `![Image alt text](./Images/MyImage.png =600x)`, it will automatically adjust the `HEIGHT` based on the scale.

Answer (score 3):

The Wiki of course support the standard HTML syntax. Please see [this blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2017/09/05/wiki-supports-html-tags-anchor-links-and-much-more/) for details.

> Q : This has all worked fine using Visual Studio Code but when the
>   markdown is pushed to the VSTS Wiki it isn't rendering the image.
>   The

The root cause is that you used a relative path, `<img src="./Images/MyImage.png" width="600">`, the image can be found on you local machine. So you can see the image when open the markdown file in Visual Studio Code locally.

However when you pushed to the VSTS, the path is changed. So it cannot find the image for rendering the image in Wiki. You need to **capture the link address (URL)** for the image, then use the URL in `img` tag like this:

```
<img src="https://xxx.visualstudio.com/f081441f-c072-4ed5-9407-85683e9b0888/_apis/git/repositories/e291904f-4668-4fba-8575-3f67898e3058/Items?path=%2Ftest%2F0116-workspace.png" width="600">
```